# Split EJS text including template in the middle

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a long text inside a variable that is rendered through EJS:

```
<% var longText = 'Very long text' %>

<%- longText %>
```

So far, so good; works fine. The thing is that I want to split this long text in two parts and have another EJS template inserted between these parts.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
text.split("<br /><br />")
// <br /><br /> is the paragraph marker
```

It returns me an array with the paragraphs of my text.
I then insert each element of the array (each paragraph) wherever I want, with whichever I want beteen elements.